# Computing the loss (MSE) for every iteration and time Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorboard

I want to use Tensorboard to plot the mean squared error (y-axis) for every iteration over a given time frame (x-axis), say 5 minutes.

However, i can only plot the MSE given every epoch and set a callback at 5 minutes. This does not however solve my problem.

I have tried looking at the internet for some solutions to how you can maybe set a maximum number of iterations rather than epochs when doing model.fit, but without luck. I know iterations is the number of batches needed to complete one epoch, but as I want to tune the batch_size, I prefer to use the iterations.

My code currently looks like the following:

```
input_size = len(train_dataset.keys())
output_size = 10
hidden_layer_size = 250
n_epochs = 3

weights_initializer = keras.initializers.GlorotUniform()

#A function that trains and validates the model and returns the MSE
def train_val_model(run_dir, hparams):
    model = keras.models.Sequential([
            #Layer to be used as an entry point into a Network
            keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
            #Dense layer 1
            keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu', 
                               kernel_initializer = weights_initializer,
                               name='Layer_1'),
            #Dense layer 2
            keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu', 
                               kernel_initializer = weights_initializer,
                               name='Layer_2'),
            #activation function is linear since we are doing regression
            keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='linear', name='Output_layer')
                                ])
    
    #Use the stochastic gradient descent optimizer but change batch_size to get BSG, SGD or MiniSGD
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.0,
                                        nesterov=False)
    
    #Compiling the model
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, 
                  loss='mean_squared_error', #Computes the mean of squares of errors between labels and predictions
                  metrics=['mean_squared_error']) #Computes the mean squared error between y_true and y_pred
    
    # initialize TimeStopping callback 
    time_stopping_callback = tfa.callbacks.TimeStopping(seconds=5*60, verbose=1)
    
    #Training the network
    history = model.fit(normed_train_data, train_labels, 
         epochs=n_epochs,
         batch_size=hparams['batch_size'], 
         verbose=1,
         #validation_split=0.2,
         callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(run_dir + "/Keras"), time_stopping_callback])
    
    return history

#train_val_model("logs/sample", {'batch_size': len(normed_train_data)})
train_val_model("logs/sample1", {'batch_size': 1})
```

```
%tensorboard --logdir_spec=BSG:logs/sample,SGD:logs/sample1
```

resulting in:

[image: x-axis: epochs, y-axis: MSE]

The desired output should look something like this:

[image: x-axis: minutes, y-axis: MSE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually quite simple.

tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard has an update_freq argument allowing you to control when to write losses and metrics to tensorboard. The standard is epoch, but you can change it to batch or an integer if you want to write to tensorboard every n batches. See the documentation for more information: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/TensorBoard

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't do it every iteration is that the loss is calculated at the end of each epoch. If you want to tune the batch size, run for a set number of epochs and evaluate. Start from 16 and jump in powers of 2 and see how much you can push the power of your network. But, usually bigger batch size is said to increase performance but it is not as substantial to solely focus on it. Focus on other things in the network first.

Comment: Run for at least 20 epochs before wanting a shape like that. That shape comes after a huge number of epochs.

Comment: The problem is that i want to visually compare the two types of gradient descent. Doing stochastic gradient descent takes way too long per one epoch, so if there is a way I could show the number of steps or iterations instead of epochs, that would make the different types of gradient descent more comparable.

Comment: Different type of gradient descent algorithms will yield different training loss and validation loss curves. Good algorithms converge fast, bad ones take time. The goodness of an algorithm in regards to neural networks are the ones that converge faster. That's why there is so much love for Adam optimizer.

Comment: The difference in computation times are because of their equations. You can do a time complexity analysis for that. One idea if you want to pursue it is to use the verbose flag, increase the verbosity. But, at that point, you will at max get epoch level.

Comment: You can use a training loop using GradientTape and control the training process, that is hard and that is what will achieve your goal.